# Sum of this Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is as follows:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{(n!)^2}$$

I tried working on it. The square in the denominator is breaking me. Please If any one could help.
And I need to find the sum of this series.

Edit:

> Important:
> Also, what's the way to evaluate the special case where $x=1,2,3 ...$
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}$$

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+of+%28-1%29%5En*x%5En%2F%28%28n%21%29%5E2%29)


Are you sure you're not mistaken?

Comment: yes i'm sure...

Comment: I hadn't read about Bessel's function. So sorry for that. And I will read about it now. :) And Thanks @HasanSaad

Comment: I already wrote a detailed answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: It's not too hard to show that $(xf')'=f$. Solution of this diff.eq. (with initial condition $f(0)=1$) is $J_0(2\sqrt x)$.

Comment: Anyone Knows...

Answer (score 2):

$$J_0(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i}}{2^{2i} (i!)^2},$$

Where $J_0$ is the zeroeth [Bessel Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). Therefore,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i x^i}{(i!)^2}=J_0(2\sqrt{x})$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}x^n$

$=\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)\Gamma(n+1)}(\sqrt{x})^2$

$=\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(n+1)}(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{2})^2$

$=J_0(2\sqrt{x})$

where $J_0(x)$ is the zeroeth Bessel's function of the first kind.

That is because by applying Frobenius method to the differential equation that defines the Bessel's equation of the first kind, we can find that

$J_\alpha(x)=\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!\Gamma(n+1+\alpha)}(\frac{x}{2})^{2m+\alpha}$.

In this case, $\alpha=0$.

Comment: By the way how can i calculate Ja(1)

Comment: You can't, it's a transcendental number.

Comment: Now this is my actual question...

Comment: Don't edit your question like that... Just edit it by adding a note at the end..

Comment: Actually I wanted to calculate the answers for x = 1,2,3 and all so asked in form of x

Comment: I don't think there's a much better way to write them other than $J_0(1),J_0(2),J_0(3)$.

You can see that on WolframAlpha

Comment: But I need the solution in the numerical form.As I am solving a problem in Numerical method,where I came across this question

Comment: Well, sorry, but I don't think I can help with that.